# php array help. Getting the correct content

Tags: php

I have an array like so:

```
Array
(
    [level] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [lvlName] => name
                    [lvlEnt] => ent
                )

        )

    [title] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => a title
                    [titleDesc] => desc here
                )

        )

    [navBar] => Products
    [pageContent] => About
)
```

Can someone please tell me how to get the pageContent?

Here is the code that I am using but I am getting undefined indexes. I have no idea where I am going wrong.

```
foreach($bigArr as $key=>$val)
{
  if($key['pageContent'] != null)
  {
    foreach($val as $fkey=>$fval)
    {
      echo $fkey['pageContent'];
    }
  }
}
```

The loops give me:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  pageContent
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Can someone please give me a hand with this?
Thanks

EDIT:
The invalid argument is what has me perplexed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the value with `$bigArr['pageContent']`.

Comment: I just figured it out. WHen I just looked at the way the array was set up I could clearly see it. Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 2):

Your first call to `foreach` is giving you two pieces of data per iteration: key and value. The key is a string, not an array (which is what you're attempting to use it as on line 3.

So on the last iteration for that array, `$key` would contain `'pageContent'` and `$val` would contain 'About'

In any case, the use of foreach for what you're doing seems unnecessary. You can directly check whether the 'pageContent' key is present in the array using [`array_key_exists()`](https://www.php.net/array_key_exists) and then pull the value straight out.

```
if(array_key_exists('pageContent', $bigArr) && $bigArr['pageContent'] != null)
{
    echo $bigArr['pageContent'];
}
```

Comment: Hey Steven, thanks very much for the example and the help. I really need to expand my function list and array_key_exists is good to have. Thank you once again!

Tom